# Is there a simple function similar to exp?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

As far as I know exp have such properties:

1. $f'(x) >0$
2. $f''(x) >0$
3. $\lim_{x \to -\infty}f(x)=0$
4. $\lim_{x \to +\infty}f(x)=\infty$
5. $f(x)f(-x)=1$

Let's say f(x) comply such rules.

The closest I can find is $f(x)=\frac{1+x|x|+x^2}{1-x|x|+x^2}$

Which does not comply the second rule.

I know it is $f'(x)=\frac{|x|}{...}$ causing the problem.

Is there a way I can tweak said function or find a new function?

P.S. I don't know which tag is correct please help me.

Edit: I know $\exp(ax+b)+c$ is a thing but I want to find a function without exponentiation or calculus stuff.

Comment: There are other such functions, for example $e^{x+cx^3}$ for sufficiently small $c>0$.

Comment: Or even simpler, $e_t(x) := \exp(tx)$ for any $t > 0$, $t \neq 1$.

Comment: maybe this fits better in https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChristianRemling thanks for you comment. I updated my question please have a look.

Comment: @M.G. thanks for you comment. I updated my question please have a look.

Comment: instead of writing exp, it is better to just write f(x)

Comment: "I want to find a function without exponentiation" In a way that is impossible, since any solution is of the form $\exp(g(x))$ with $g$ an odd function with $g' > 0$ and $(g')^2 + g'' > 0$. But perhaps there is a solution with a better formulation without exponentiation.

Comment: @ThomasKojar Thanks for your comment! The functional equation f(x)f(-x)=1 itself won't reduce back to exponential since (|A|+Bx)/(|A|-Bx) is also a solution.

Comment: if assume analytic it will https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747258/all-solutions-of-fxf-x-1

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3747258/all-solutions-of-fxf-x-1
a general solution for the functional equation $f(x)f(-x)=1$ is

> You can simply pick any $h:\mathbb{R}_{>0}\to\mathbb{R}_{\neq 0}$ and $\epsilon\in\{-1,+1\}$.  Then, define the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ by
> $$f(x):=\left\{\begin{array}{ll}
> h(x)&\text{if }x>0\,,\\
> \epsilon&\text{if }x=0\,,\\
> \dfrac{1}{h(-x)}&\text{if }x<0\,.
> \end{array}\right.$$
> Then, $f$ satisfies the required functional equation.  Note that any such function $f$ takes the form above.

So lets just take $h(x)=x^2$.

If you further ask for smooth you get exponential-like

> It turns out that the solutions are $f(x)=\epsilon\,\exp\big(g(x)\big)$, where $\epsilon\in\{-1,+1\}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a smooth or analytic, odd function.  If you want $f$ to be just $k$-time differentiable, then $g$ is $k$-time differentiable.

Comment: Take $h(x) =2 x^2+2x+2$ to get $f'$ and $f''$ continuous.